# Вывод общего количества созданных странниц в XSL FO

Tags: xml, xslt

Для создания pdf использую xsl fo. Проблема возникла при необходимости разделять нумерацию страниц для разных page-sequence регионов, то есть у каждого `page-sequence` стоят атрибуты  `initial-page-number="1"` `force-page-count="no-force"`. Собственно из-за этого и возник вопрос.

При подобном построении регионов получается, что счетчик нумерации страниц `page-number` каждый раз сбрасывается до 1 и при попытке вывести `page-number-citation` выводит количество страниц последнего `page-sequence`.

Есть ли какой-то альтернативный вариант вывода общего количества всех страниц в документе?